# Serializing a simple array with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Its late and fully possible I'm missing something obvious but what is it?

I'm trying to create a backing property which reveals an int array as serialized (which is then used to build up a Queue).

I'm pretty sure this is right but the getter always return a blank string, even when there are values in there (not that it should ever return a blank string.

Here is my code:

```
readonly Lazy<XmlSerializer> _queueSerializer = new Lazy<XmlSerializer>(() => new XmlSerializer(typeof(int[])));
[StringLength(1000)]
public string _MostRecentPlayers
{
    get
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        _queueSerializer.Value.Serialize(stream, _mostRecentPlayers.ToArray());
        return new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.IsEmpty())
        {
            _mostRecentPlayers.Clear();
            return;
        }
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value));
        var tempQueue = _queueSerializer.Value.Deserialize(stream) as int[];
        _mostRecentPlayers.Clear();
        tempQueue.ForEach(_mostRecentPlayers.Enqueue);
    }
}
readonly Queue<int> _mostRecentPlayers = new Queue<int>(_mostRecentAmountTracked);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't rewound the stream; it is positioned at the end. Set `.Position = 0` before reading it. Or easier, just serialize to a `StringWriter`, or if you really want to use a `MemoryStream`, pass the (oversized) backing array from `GetBuffer()` **along with the `.Length`** to an `Encoding` and call `GetString()`.

```
using(var sw = new StringWriter()) {
    _queueSerializer.Value.Serialize(sw, _mostRecentPlayers.ToArray());
    xml = sw.ToString();
}
```

or for ASCII (see comments):

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
        Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
    };
    using(var xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings)) {
        _queueSerializer.Value.Serialize(xw, _mostRecentPlayers.ToArray());
    }
    xml = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
}
```

Also, unless it is *unlikely* that you will serialize in the exe, I would suggest simplifying to just:

```
static readonly XmlSerializer _queueSerializer =new XmlSerializer(typeof(int[]));
```

Finally, note that xml is quite verbose as a mechansim to throw some ints around. CSV would seem a lot simpler (assuming you want text).

Comment: I just found a tip to use StringWriter elsewhere too. How do I specify it to use ASCII though?

Comment: @George - if it must be ASCII, then firstly note that you *really* need to spin up an XmlWriter explicitly - otherwise the encoding is wrong. I'll add an example.